# Angular Universal does not work with Angular Google Maps

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal, angular-google-maps

**Tech**: Angular Cli, Angular version 7, Angular Google Maps, Firebase Functions.

**Issue**: I'm trying to serve my angular universal app but getting an error for angular google maps when building.

**Error** I get:

```
/Users/test/Public/Leisure/leisure-app/functions/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/info-window-manager.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
Observable } from 'rxjs';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
```

Seems that Angular Universal doesnt like third party libraries.

**The resource I followed:** https://hackernoon.com/deploying-angular-universal-v6-with-firebase-c86381ddd445

**My App Module:**

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxErrorsModule } from '@hackages/ngxerrors';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TruncateModule } from 'ng2-truncate';
import { MetaModule } from '@ngx-meta/core';
import { PreventDoubleSubmitModule } from 'ngx-prevent-double-submission';

// Core App
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreInterceptor } from './interceptor';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// Modules
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from './services/core.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layouts/layout.module';

// Sections
import { COMPONENTS } from './components/index';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';

// Guards
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { CreditGuard } from './guards/credit.guard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    COMPONENTS
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,

    // This is the Angular google maps module causing issue on build
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.googleApiKey,
      libraries: ['places']
    }),

    GooglePlaceModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'test123' }),
    PreventDoubleSubmitModule.forRoot(),
    TruncateModule,
    MetaModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxErrorsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CoreInterceptor, multi: true },
    AuthGuard,
    CreditGuard,
    AngularFireDatabase
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Command I run: serve**: npm run build && firebase serve --only functions

**Latest Error (for npm run serve:ssr):**

[image]

**Error code from serve:ssr:**

```
e.Lb=function(a,b,c){a=this.ka.J[String(a)];if(!a)return!0;a=a.concat();for(var d=!0,f=0;f<a.length;++f){var g=a[f];if(g&&!g.Sa&&g.capture==b){var k=g.listener,p=g.Ob||g.src;g.Eb&&this.Le(g);d=!1!==k.call(p,c)&&d;}}return d&&0!=c.Be};e.jb=function(a,b,c,d){return this.ka.jb(String(a),b,c,d)};var ub=h.JSON.stringify;function vb(a,b){this.Sf=100;this.ef=a;this.ug=b;this.Zb=0;this.Pb=null;}vb.prototype.get=function(){if(0<this.Zb){this.Zb--;var a=this.Pb;this.Pb=a.next;a.next=null;}else a=this.ef();return a};vb.prototype.put=function(a){this.ug(a);this.Zb<this.Sf&&(this.Zb++, a.next=this.Pb, this.Pb=a);};function I(){this.lc=this.Va=null;}var xb=new vb(function(){return new wb},function(a){a.reset();});I.prototype.add=function(a,b){var c=this.Af();c.set(a,b);this.lc?this.lc.next=c:this.Va=c;this.lc=c;};I.prototype.remove=function(){var a=null;this.Va&&(a=this.Va, this.Va=this.Va.next, this.Va||(this.lc=null), a.next=null);return a};I.prototype.wg=function(a){xb.put(a);};I.prototype.Af=function(){return xb.get()};function wb(){this.next=this.scope=this.Gc=null;}
wb.prototype.set=function(a,b){this.Gc=a;this.scope=b;this.next=null;};wb.prototype.reset=function(){this.next=this.scope=this.Gc=null;};function yb(a){h.setTimeout(function(){throw a;},0);}var zb;
```

Comment: I've read in some places that you can white list the third party libraries using a webpack config file. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: The comments in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200) may give you a few hints. [One comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200#issuecomment-320457279) suggests using `import-export` or disabling AoT compiling as workarounds. [Another comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200#issuecomment-388387118) suggests adding `--bundle-dependencies=all` to the `ng build` command or `"bundleDependencies": "all"` to the `configurations` in `angular.json`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan those links dont seem to work for an angular version 7 app

Comment: @AngularM before you say it's not working in v7 have a look here, don't know if you tried with `ng`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996655/angular-js-2-difference-between-npm-and-ngangular-cli-built-tool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

[**Source code**](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-agm) and 
**[DEMO](https://angular-agm.firebaseapp.com/)**

[image]

---

The issue here is that `@agm/core` package is compiled with es2015 module. As a result, it contains `import` and `export` in js code.

To remedy this you have two main options:

## 1. Compile @agm/core package to commonjs format.

You can use either babel or typescript to compile that package. Then you need to make sure you provided compiled version in your functions dependencies

**functions/package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@agm/core": "file:./@agm/core"
},
```

Here I use local dependency but you can also use your own published version.

Another method would be compile directly in node_modules and publish the whole node_modules(**I would avoid this**):

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "functions": {
    "ignore": []
  }
}
```

### How to compile?

**Babel**

Install dependencies in root directory.

```
npm i -D @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Use the following script to compile:

**package.json**

```
"postbuild": "babel node_modules/@agm/core -d functions/@agm/core --presets @babel/preset-env && node ./copy-package-json.js"
```

where

**copy-package-json.js**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const { join } = require('path');

(async() => {
  await fs.copy(join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/@agm/core/package.json'),
                join(process.cwd(), 'functions/@agm/core/package.json'));
})();
```

**Typescript**

**tsconfig.agm.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./functions/@agm/core",
    "types": [],
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@agm/core"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"postbuild": "tsc -p tsconfig.agm.json --allowJs && node ./copy-package-json.js"
```

## 2. Generate server bundle

This is what Angular universal [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/universal) uses so **I prefer this solution**.

Also follow this [quide](https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/)

Simple steps:

---

**1. Install global dependencies**

I have installed:

- @angular/cli@7.3.8
- firebase-tools@6.5.2

**2. Create a new Angular project**

```
ng new angular-agm
```

**3. Add Angular universal**

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular-agm
```

**4. Update server.ts**

Export the express app, then remove the call to listen and change index to index2.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';
import * as path from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
export const app = express();

// const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

const index = require('fs')
  .readFileSync(path.resolve(DIST_FOLDER, 'index2.html'), 'utf8')
  .toString();

const domino = require('domino');
const win = domino.createWindow(index);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index2', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
/*app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});*/
```

**5. Build**

```
npm run build:ssr
```

where build:ssr

```
"build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && node ./tools/copy-artifacts.js",
```

**copy-artifacts.js**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const { join } = require('path');

(async() => {
  const src = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const copy = join(process.cwd(), 'functions/dist');

  await fs.rename(join(src, 'browser/index.html'), join(src, 'browser/index2.html'));
  await fs.remove(copy);
  await fs.copy(src, copy);
})();
```

**6. Update functions/index.js** to use built version of express app

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { app } = require('./dist/server');

exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**7. Configure firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The source code can be found on [Github](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-agm)

See also demo https://angular-agm.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191544/discussion-on-answer-by-yurzui-angular-universal-not-work-with-angular-google-ma).

Comment: Currently the html doesnt render when deploy, but works locally using firebase serve. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you manage to find out how to solve the AngularFire error for angular universal: "TypeError: app.auth is not a function"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any reproducible example.

Comment: can you add angularfire and firebase to your github app and see if you get the same error @yurzui ?

Comment: Hey, yes I will try it later.

Comment: I've added it to my repo https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-agm/commit/e9c4a924355cf6e444c42458632e596ee35bc289 Here's the live preview https://angular-agm.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Seems I need to add `AngularFireAuthModule` as well since the error comes from that module.

Comment: Yes, now I got it. I will take a look later.

Comment: I got it working for me. https://angular-agm.firebaseapp.com/ Please take a look at this commit. https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-agm/commit/251cae6e5d5c11ffcf05001e51ed2d746af0585c The key point is `"engines": {"node": "8"},` Another way that worked is to upload the whole node_modules to the functions. Note that we do not even need `@firebase/app` dependency in `functions/package.json`

Comment: @yurzui could the issue be with the webpack config and the regex: const regex = /firebase\/(app|firestore)/;  for externals?

Comment: ??? Does  `"engines": {"node": "8"}` work for you? We configured externals since we got others errors which related to wrong bundle proccess for firebase-sdk. It couldn't work with nodejs environment directly. Exposing it as externals we said that the nodejs should process firebase deps itself. The problem is that firebase functions hosting can't correctly install dependencies if node version is 6. If you push the whole node_modules then it will also work

Comment: should i add "engines": {"node": "8"} to webpack config?

Comment: Looks like you didn't see my commit https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-agm/blob/251cae6e5d5c11ffcf05001e51ed2d746af0585c/functions/package.json#L17-L19

Comment: It works! only issue is the firestore page breaks when viewing source: https://behired-staging.firebaseapp.com/job-board

Comment: I think you need to create another issue on this since we went so far from the original Angular Google Map issue

Comment: @yurzui im going to give you the 500 now and make a new question for the firestore issue with ssr. Thanks for your help. been amazing! will you help me with the firestore data issue ? il post the link to the question in the comments

Comment: @yurzui I've got one more issue related to this question regarding firestore database not rendering for ssr: could you take a look please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634099/angular-universal-ssr-not-work-for-pages-that-use-firebase-firestore-database

Comment: @yurzui I've noticed that with ssr when I try jump to a page in the address bar e.g: https://behired.co.uk/blog it takes a long time to load. Whats the reason for this? I thought ssr would be fast rendering of the html. But it seems to take a long time to load pages?